# Google Cloud BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a set of data (x, y) where x = 1 to 5 , y = 1 to 10
e.g. extract from them one by one where (1,1),(1,2),(1,3)…(1,10)…(2,5)…(5,10)

```
BEGIN
DECLARE
  x,y INT64 DEFAULT 0;
LOOP
SET
  x = x + 1;
IF
  x <= Max(x) THEN
LOOP
SET
  y = y + 1;
IF
  y <= Max(y) THEN
CALL
  data(x,y);
  ELSE
BREAK;
END IF;
END LOOP;
END IF;
END LOOP;
END
```

Does anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I think `CROSS JOIN` with `GENERATE_ARRAY` will works better for you

```
SELECT * FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1,5)) x, UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1,10)) y
```

Is it?